# error while using onTap function inside ListTile

Tags: flutter, dart

while using onTap function i got this error Function expressions can't be named.
Try removing the name, or moving the function expression to a function declaration statement.

```
                    ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.home),
                      title: Text('Home'),
                      onTap() =>Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),)
                      )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a ':' after onTap.  It should read:

```
ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.home),
        title: Text('Home'),
        onTap: () => Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen())));
```